# Ruby: Split hash to folder names

Tags: ruby

How to make from

```
f6f6c3408e67bf6473d65de172f0e5da.jpg
```

file name

That structure of folder `f6/f6/c3/40/8e/67/bf/64/73/d6/5d/e1/72/f0/e5/da.jpg` to escape file system overload

Comment: With such pathes you can make more file/system overload. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
'f6f6c3408e67bf6473d65de172f0e5da.jpg'.sub /(.*)(\..*)/ do 
    filename, extension = $1, $2
    filename.scan(/../).join('/') + extension
end
```

Comment: Please keep in mind any potential performance problems.  If this piece is critical consider some other solutions that don't involve regexps and temporary arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you follow what systems like `git` do and just extract the first two characters to make a directory and put the files in it. Creating so many directories for this seems pointless (and might affect performance too ) and if it works for systems like `git` to avoid inefficiencies of the file system, it should work for you too. And of course, if you follow this approach, the implementation is going to pretty simple as well.

```
directory,filename = filename[0..1],filename[2..-1]
```